# Can I detach the buffer from a std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I'm new to C++. I was assuming `std::string` uses a reference count to determine when to release the buffer. In the following example, `s` buffer will be released when `f()` returns. What if I wanted to give ownership of the string buffer to `give_ownership_of` and not to release it?

```
void f() 
{ 
    string s = read_str();  
    give_ownership_of(s); 
}
```

**UPDATE**

Let me add more details into the question. The actual code looks like this,

```
string read_str();

void write_str_async(const char *str, void (*free_fn)(const char*));

void f() {
  string s = read_str();
  // write_str_async() need to access the buffer of s after f() returns.
  // So I'm responsible to keep s alive until write_str_async() calls free_fn to release the buffer when the write is done.
  // The PROBLEM here is that s will be released when the variable scope ends. NOTE: I'm not able to change either read_str() or write_str_async() here.
  write_str_async(s.c_str(), my_free_fn);
}
```

Comment: Some implementations **do** use a reference-count mechanism internally.  Is it causing you a problem?

Comment: Do you have any particular reason why you want to get ownership of internal `char*` buffer instead of passing `std::string` object?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done???

Comment: Describe your situation in more detail. Why do you need a `std::string` object to give you the ownership of its internal buffer?

Comment: What you're trying to do defeats data encapsulation.  Why do you want access to another objects internals?

Comment: It's not even guaranteed that such a buffer exists, and in fact modern `std::string` implementations don't use one for small strings. ("Small String Optimization"). In such cases, `s.c_str()` will point to the stack, inside `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to take ownership of the underlying data of a `std::string`.  Generally, one should instead return a string object itself or have the caller pass in a reference, e.g.

```
void f(std::string& s) {
    s = read_str();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++11, they added something like this, called a move. `std::string` has a move constructor and a move assignment operator.

The compiler here can determine that `s` has reached the end of its lifetime, so rather than copying into `give_ownership_of` it can move, which is basically just copying a few integers / pointers around, rather than the contents of the `std::string`. Note that this is still slower than passing by reference, so if a reference works for you, you should prefer that regardless.

https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/move-constructor/

I would strongly recommend against using `std::shared_ptr` for this, as there is no actual sharing of ownership.

In cases where you want to make the move explicit, then you would do this:

```
give_ownership_of(std::move(s));
```

Note that you do not need to (and in fact should not) use `std::move` when returning a value from a function. Just return the value normally. The compiler can in many cases perform "return value optimization", which means that there is no copy and no move. It's similar to passing the value in by reference and assigning to that, except it actually gives the optimizer a little more room (because it knows that the `std::string` is a unique object that doesn't alias anything). It's also more straightforward to read.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous but the examples below should illustrate all the alternatives. The last one is probably what you want, and it's a new feature added in C++11 (`std::move` and rvalue references).

This allows you to transfer the buffer to a new object of the same type, but you can never eliminate `std::string` entirely. You can ignore that `string` and treat the buffer memory as bytes, but deallocation must be performed by destroying a `string`.

```
// will retain s for duration of function
void give_ownership_of( std::string &s );

// will retain a copy of s for duration of function
void give_ownership_of( std::string s );

struct give_ownership_of {
     std::string s;

     // will retain a copy of in_s for object lifetime
     give_ownership_of( std::string const &in_s ) : s( in_s ) {}

     // will transfer buffer of in_s to s and retain that (C++11 only)
     // you would write give_ownership_of( std::move( s ) );
     give_ownership_of( std::string &&in_s ) : s( std::move( in_s ) ) {}
};
```